# how can i run code when an application ends with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications

how can i run code when an application ends with asp.net mvc ?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit?  what do you mean by "ends with asp.net mvc?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_End()
{
}
```

Comment: hahaha i ve been trying Application_Finish thx man